# How to change the Time zone

Tags: jquery, time, zone

I have used `jquery.time-to.min.js` for a clock.

It shows the current time on clock. And the client is from Austria, how do I change the time zone to austria by using this plugin?

This is how I have initialized the script :

```
$('#clock-1').timeTo();
```

Comment: so austrian clients should see a different value on the timer?

Comment: Austrian clients should see a Austrian time on the timer

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, there is nothing *you* can do using this plugin.**

The simple digital clock discussed [here](https://lexxus.github.io/jq-timeTo/#countdown-3) explains that it displays "current system time," which means that whatever the user has the time set to on their computer is the time the clock will show. Hopefully users in Austria have their computer clocks set to the timezone they are in, or the timeTo clock, just like their computer clock, will be wrong.

I actually set my clock to an incorrect timezone and refreshed the timeTo clock, and it also was set to that time.